# Корректна ли пунктуация при обороте со словом "точнее"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

*Драка в понедельник на митинге национал-консерваторов из EKRE открыла новую страницу в политической культуре – точнее, в политическом бескультурье – Эстонии.*
А. Титов. [Чем мы не Уганда?](https://www.mke.ee/mnenie/andrej-titov-chem-my-ne-uganda). МК-Эстония, 28.11.2018

Мне кажется – что-то тут неправильно, никак не соображу **что**.
Верно ли поставлены тире? Поделитесь своим мнением.

Answer (score 4):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно:

*Драка в понедельник на митинге национал-консерваторов из EKRE открыла новую страницу в политической культуре – точнее, в политическом бескультурье – Эстонии.*

Правило Розенталя, которое касается слов ***точнее, вернее*** здесь не следует применять, так как **отсутствует значение уточнения, равнозначности смысла.**

Драка в понедельник на митинге национал-консерваторов из EKRE открыла новую страницу в политической культуре – точнее, в политическом бескультурье – Эстонии.

Это **вставная конструкция** со значением дополнительного замечания иронического характера.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

4. В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо тире, могут быть еще запятые.

Здесь возможны следующие случаи:
1) с обеих сторон ставится **только тире**, если в месте вставки дополнительных сведений **не должно быть никакого знака препинания:** Аннушка молча покинула свою засаду, тихо обошла кругом — её детские ножки едва шумели по густой траве — и вышла из чащи подле самого старика (Т.); И — бывают же чудеса — подковылял Воропаев (Павл.); Кругом — не обнять глазом — снежная пелена (Ш.);

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (правка стиля)

(1) *Драка в понедельник на митинге национал-консерваторов из EKRE открыла новую страницу в политической культуре Эстонии — вернее,  в её политическом бескультурье.*

(2) *Драка в понедельник на митинге национал-консерваторов из EKRE открыла новую страницу в политической культуре Эстонии, а вернее,  в её политическом бескультурье.*

Comment: Есть и в Нацкорпусе  примеры с двумя тире, скорее всего, там авторы тоже  думают, что это  вставная конструкция (*«Убожество», ― отреагировал на это глава администрации президента РФ Сергей Иванов, и его слова ― точнее, слово ― не цитирует теперь только ленивый. [Мария Цырулева. Враги и убожество // «Русский репортер», 2015]*).  Как бы от ни было, "одинокое" слово после тире в конце предложения вызывает чувство неприятия, неправильности.

Comment: Слова и слово - это примерно одно и то же,  и авторы могли бы оформить предложение по Розенталю, если бы они его читали. Но вот культура и бескультурье - это вроде бы антонимы, какая уж тут  равнозначность смысла. Думаю, что Розенталь тоже использовал бы здесь вставную конструкцию.

Comment: Кроме того, автор имеет право  использовать вставку, если ему важно особо выделить из текста какое-либо замечание и если структура предложения позволяет это сделать (то есть мы можем убрать вставную конструкцию из предложения без его перестройки). Главное - это содержание, а форма должна наилучшим образом ему соответствовать.

Comment: Ксения, надо внести ясность. Я удалил свой ответ, но так или иначе, предложение  составлено неудачно и "не звучит".   Как вариант исправления:  *...открыла новую страницу в политической культуре Эстонии – точнее, в политическом бескультурье.*

Comment: Да, в таком виде предложение воспринимается лучше (я к этому тоже склонялась). И спасибо за хорошую правку – ТАК всем всё понятно.

Comment: @М_Г Давайте внесем ясность. 1) Я не понимаю. зачем Вы удалили свой ответ. Были варианты, было их нормальное обсуждение, какой и почему лучше. Это же нормально и интересно. 2) Новый вариант правки мне не нравится, старый вариант - тоже не идеал  (я как-то на пунктуацию больше обращала внимание, чем на стиль). Поэтому предложу в ответе еще один вариант.

Comment: @Ксения, Вы меня убедили, что мой ответ ошибочен, а не просто хуже. Сохранять его ради истории?

Comment: А Вы еще раз ответьте, предложите тот вариант, который считаете правильным. Только лучше в начале ответа записывать предложение полностью, а потом объяснять его.